# "Scorretto" versus "incorretto"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, adjectives, difference

Ho trovato nel dizionario questi due aggettivi, "scorretto" e "incorretto", che a me sembrano molto simili. Una semplice ricerca su Google mostra però che "incorretto" è molto meno usato di "scorretto". Potreste spiegarmi le differenze di uso tra questi due vocaboli?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La parola *scorretto* significa *non corretto*, *sbagliato*. L'accezione richiamata da EndovenosaSorella (corrispondente all'inglese *unfair*) non è l'unica di *scorretto*. Un ragionamento può essere *scorretto* senza che l'autore sia in malafede. La semplificazione della frazione 64/16=4/1 in cui si cancellano i due 6 è scorretta, pur producendo un risultato corretto.

Secondo il [dizionario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/incorretto/), *incorretto* significa *non corretto* nel senso che *non è stato sottoposto a correzione* ed è di uso raro come sinonimo di *scorretto*.

Invece che *raro*, la mia opinione è che sia un anglismo: in inglese *scorretto* nel senso di errato/sbagliato si dice *incorrect* e la nota mania di italianizzare l'inglese fa il resto.

Comment: Effettivamente anche al mio orecchio “incorretto” suona di calco dall'inglese, ma se lo è, è una specie di calco di ritorno (come “prova” per dire “dimostrazione”), perché in testi d'epoca si trova tranquillamente, come [qui](http://tinyurl.com/ngunjqt) (ma attenzione agli errori di digitalizzazione in cui si dovrebbe avere in realtà “incorrotto”).

Comment: Dunque, se ho capito bene, potrei dire: gli esami dei miei alunni sono ancora incorretti.

Comment: @Charo Potresti, ma sarebbe piuttosto insolito. Meglio *non ho ancora corretto le prove d'esame dei miei studenti*.

Comment: @DaG: Interessante questa citazione del *Vocabolario Cateriniano* di Girolamo Gigli: «Il Vocabolario ha *incorrigibile* non già *incorretto*; ha *scomposto* e *incomposto*, e *sconsiderato* e *inconsiderato*, e *inonesto* e *disonesto*, e *invenire* e *svanire*, e *invergognare* e *svergognare*; ma, ammettendosi *scorretto*, non si vuol ricevere *incorretto*: il perchè sta racchiuso fra gli altri segreti della tramoggia, che si sapranno il dì del giudizio.»

Comment: Forse dovremo aspettare fino al Giorno del Giudizio per sapere perché "incorretto" è oggi piuttosto in disuso. :-D

Answer (score 1):

'Scorretto' implica malafede, la mancanza di rispetto di regole. Esempi: 'giocatore scorretto', 'guidare in modo scorretto'. Tradurrei in inglese con 'unfair'.

'Incorretto' invece è simile a 'non esatto'. Esempio: se rispondo che 2 + 2 = 5, la mia risposta è incorretta. Tradurrei in inglese con 'incorrect' o 'wrong'.

Le due parole derivano ovviamente da 'corretto', che ha entrambi i significati positivi (rispettoso delle regole / esatto), l'esatta accezione si evince dal contesto.

Comment: Il [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/scorretto/) però indica che *scorretto* ha anche questo significato: «che presenta errori o inesattezze, spec. di lingua, di stile o di tecnica: *una traduzione scorretta*; *un tema vivace ma scorretto*; *un disegno debole e scorretto*; *esecuzione scorretta di un brano musicale*».

Answer (score -1):

'Scorretto', che è tutto ciò che non è corretto, è di uso comune tanto nella lingua parlata che in quella scritta, tanto nell'università quanto al fruttivendolo, sì.

'Incorretto' è un vocabolo inesistente nella realtà — ancorché esistente nel vocabolario — tanto che ad usarlo potresti generare una fragorosa risata dell'interlocutore.

Un'alternativa a 'scorretto', comunque meno enfatica e meno usabile, è 'non corretto'.

Comment: Le tue convinzioni possono essere rispettabili (personalmente eviterei *incorretto*, per esempio), ma se una parola è registrata nei dizionari, non può essere classificata come “inesistente”. Secondo il Treccani, l'uso di *incorretto* come sinonimo di *scorretto* è raro.

Comment: @egreg Non ho detto 'inesistente', ma 'inesistente nella realtà'.

Comment: Fino a prova contraria i lessicografi ne sanno più di noi e hanno sotto mano corpora che vanno dalle opere degli inizi del volgare a registrazioni di testi orali contemporanei. E, come accennavo in un altro commento, già un corpus molto ridotto non conferma che questa parola sia “inesistente nella realtà”. ES, al massimo puoi dire che le persone che frequenti tu e i testi che leggi tu non lo usano.

Comment: Io non solo frequento persone, ma leggo un po' di tutto, vado a cinema, teatro e ascolto musica italiana, guardo la TV. Sicché, salvo che non mi sia perso qualche ristretto circolo di intellettualoidi, ti assicuro che non lo usa nessuno. @DaG

Comment: ES, ho l'impressione che non sia così che si costruiscono i corpora linguistici. E se anche tu avessi la possibilità di cogliere tutto il mutevole panorama della lingua italiana dalle Alpi a Pantelleria e dai postriboli agli atenei, ci sarebbe ancora tutto un millennio di storia della lingua di cui tenere conto (“italiano” non significa “italiano qui e ora”).